# Scrapy Error Invalid xPath Expression When Building URL List

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm scraping apartments.com with Scrapy. I want to go to every page in the form of `apartments.com/boston-ma/X` where X is an integer representing the page number.

Once there, I want to extract all of the property URLs, which all have the class of `property-link`. And then I'm going to write a parse_item for each property.

I'm getting the error

> ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //*[contains(@class,
> 'property-link'')]/@href

I have no idea what's wrong with my xPath. Please advise.

Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from apt.items import AptItem
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class AptSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "apt"
    allowed_domains = ["apartments.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.apartments.com/boston-ma/"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'[1-9]+/*'), callback='parse_urls', follow=True),)

    def parse_urls(self, response):
        apts = response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'property-link'')]/@href").extract()
        for a in apts:
            url = urljoin(response.url, a)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=parse_item)


    #def parse_item(self, response):
        #scrape data here
        #item = AptItem()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write
 `apts = response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'property-link'')]/@href").extract()`
You have to write
`apts = response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'property-link')]/@href").extract()`
You are adding 'property-link'' two inverted commas. After property-link